# In discord.py, how do you use guild.create_role()?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord, discord.py

Consider the code

```
@CLIENT.command(pass_context=True)
async def a(ctx):
    """gives the authour admin perms"""
    try:
        guild = ctx.guild
        await guild.create_role(name="admin", permissions=discord.Permissions(8), colour=discord.Colour(0xff0000))
        authour = ctx.message.author
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="admin")
        await authour.add_roles(role)
    except:
        print("something went wrong (A)")
```

When I try this command the code awaits forever on guild.create_role()

Why might that be? What might I change in order to make this code work?

Thank you!

Comment: Honestly, I am stumped. I looked through the [discord.py API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_role), but couldn't find anything. Are you completely sure the issue is on `guild.create_role()`?

Comment: `user.server.roles` should be `authour.guild.roles`.

Answer (score 4):

One specific problem I see is using `.server`, it has been changed to `.guild` in the rewrite and `user` is not defined

You can assign the new role to a variable, so you dont need to get the role

```py
@CLIENT.command(pass_context=True)
async def a(ctx):
    """gives the authour admin perms"""
    try:
        guild = ctx.guild
        role = await guild.create_role(name="admin", permissions=discord.Permissions(8), colour=discord.Colour(0xff0000))
        authour = ctx.message.author
        await authour.add_roles(role)
    except:
        print("something went wrong (A)")
```